# Decoupling command (pattern) sending classes from receivers?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

So in order to create commands (based on the pattern) in any class, that class has to know about the receiver class in order to pass it into the constructor of the command, which then couples the classes together. Is there a way to use the command pattern and keep a measure of indirection between the two classes?

The only solutions I can think of are:

- Use a mediator, but how exactly I don't know since at the least the command would still need to be passed the class even if it was just its interface
- Use a facade, but that couples any command calling class to the facade
- Use an event system instead of commands, but that has too much overhead in execution and just writing the code itself
- Use a creation pattern to make the commands somehow but that couples everything to that object

My biggest concern with the event system is that from my experience with event systems the amount of code you have to write to get the sender and receiver interacting without knowing about each other is insane and not practical at all- every method I want accessible by an event requires me to modify at least one other class and usually more, which creates problems just as bad as tightly coupled spegetti code. Also I usually need classes to send responses to events which is also very cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command pattern isn't meant to decouple the creator and the receiver; these classes are usually already coupled or may even be the same class.

What the command pattern does is decouple the implementation from the class which *executes the command*. Once the command has been created, it can be passed to the UI layer or over the network to a remote client, and the executing class does not require any knowledge of how the command is implemented.

Comment: In that case what creation patterns would be good to use with command? Would the creation object be placed on the receiver and then maybe accessed through a property implemented through a command creator interface? If that is the case then would it make sense to have classes where only command creation interfaces are exposed if you want to regulate its interaction with other classes?

Comment: @Ford: It depends on your use case. It might be difficult to come up with a generic creation interface because different commands might require different parameters for creation.

Comment: Yea... I'm trying to go for something where I can make a subclass of the command depend on the same interface as the receiver so that rather than making new subclasses of that command for each new method, adding methods to the interface automatically makes them available to the client...

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use a façade. If you're putting a façade in your design from the beginning, you probably need to rethink your design.  The façade's main purpose is to hide away code with which you want to simplify the interaction - typically legacy code. New code should ideally be designed with the simpler interface from the beginning.

Without knowing more about your specific problem, I have a few suggestions:

1. **Go ahead and use the event system.** C# has a fantastic event system that you can take advantage of without writing too much of your own code; simply define a few delegates and add event handlers, and you're most of the way there. The mechanics of sending events are abstracted away so that most of your job is wiring them together.  If you haven't used events much before, some quick searching should give you plenty of useful information.
2. **Specify the receiver on execute:**

   ```
   public interface ICommand {
       public void Execute(IReceiver receiver);
   }
   ```

   This allows the receiver to dynamically change when `Execute()` is called, which makes this use of the pattern serve as a way to pass behaviors around your system.  At this point, though, there's a better way to achieve the same result...
3. **Pass functions around, rather than objects.**  C# once again comes to the rescue, permitting functions to be passed around the system like any other data type.  Specify your command as a delegate:

   ```
   class MyThing {
       public delegate void Command(IReceiver receiver);

       public static void PrintReceiver(IReceiver receiver){
            // print the receiver
       }

       public static void ChangeReceiver(IReceiver receiver){
            // change something about the receiver
       }
   }
   ```

   Which later allows you to do things like this:

   ```
   IReceiver receiver = someReceiverThatAlreadyExists;
   Command action = someCondition ? MyThing.PrintReceiver : MyThing.ChangeReceiver;
   action(receiver);
   ```

   Which is an overly simplistic example, but illustrates how you can have a behavior that acts like a command, but without needing a full object.

Comment: Delegates are cool but I'm not sure that solution deals with the problems I mentioned...

Answer (score 1):

You can have

```
public interface ICommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand 
{
    void Execute(T command);
}
```

Of course this will require some routing code to transfer your command from issuer to receiver. But if you base this routing on conventions, that should be not so hard write-once code.

(I'm basing this on the idea that command should have single, well-defined consumer. If that is not the case, then this is maybe an event, and that is a bit different, as there interested parties are subscribing to events by themselves).

Comment: That sounds pretty nice... command subclasses could then contain an interface member defining the receiver so that any new methods I want to expose on the receiver automatically become available. Then for routing I could use a mediator or something, that would see if the colleague had the same interface as the command then plug it into the command and execute it. Does that sound like a good idea?

Comment: How you define receiver in command is up to you; depends on how much decoupling you want. You can e.g. define recipient type, or you can just define recipient name and let mediator find it for you.